# Content DIV not pushing footer down

Tags: css, html, footer

i have a problem with a stuck down footer not been pushed down by 2x DIVs in the main content area.

www.superwideprint.com/swp2

for some reason the 2 content containers arnt pushing the footer down when the screen resolution is low, i have added a clear:both div above the footer but to no avail.

can anyone help me please.

style sheet and main page can be seen from the link above. been at this for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer's position is set to absolute, so the content div is not going to affect it. Setting the position to relative will not help either, as this means your bottom: 0 code will push it to the bottom of whatever it is in, not the page.

What you're after is a sticky footer, try this http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ or http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: thanks for input guys, tried the above links to no avail. if you look at link again you can see what im trying to achieve =) did i mess it up?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the `#footer` DIV is `position:absolute`. So, remove `position:absolute` form your footer.

A part from that your want your footer always stay at bottom then you can use **Sticky Footer** technique. Check this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: i tried the coding in the example and i couldnt get it to work?

Comment: create two div first #container(in which whole content & other things come) with height 100% & second #footer

Comment: thats done something different, if you look at link again its pushed footer to bottom, but now i have a load of blank space? i created "main" DIV and threw everything in there. and footer div sits below "main".

Comment: threw table & #wrap also. Check the link HTML structure